# Using " until " or " by"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

Which of the preposition is most suitable to use;

I) I will have finished my thesis by March.

II) I will have finished my thesis until March.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, you can't *finish something until a specific time*, since *finishing* is a **sudden action** and *until* emphasises duration; in other words, *if something happens until a particular time, it **continues and then stops at that time*** as in

> The ticket is valid until March.
>
> You have to stay here until March.

*By*, on the other hand, means  *before or not later than a particular time* as in

> The documents need to be ready by next Friday.
>
> You need to finish your paper by Tuesday.

In your case then, I'd definitely go with *by* and not *until*.

Answer (score 1):

*'by'* sets the deadline. This means the work should be **finished** **before that time**. Here, in this case, the thesis' deadline is the month of March.

*'until/till'* talks about something that is **continued from one point to another.** Say - "I will wait for you *till* 2 o'clock". This means *from this point of time to 2 o'clock'*.

An example:

> She's sick. She needs to be in bed **till** 10 o'clock.

This means from one point of time to 10 o'clock, she should be in her bed.

But ...

> She's sick. She needs to be in bed **by** 10 o'clock.

sets the deadline that no matter where she is, she has to be in her bed before clock strikes 10.

In your example, *'..**by** March...'* is the choice.

Comment: @JavaLatte I buy your words! :)